# Matlab: Projective Projection of image not correct/working

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am creating a demo app for performing geometric transformations and I have following equation:

```
X= x/((2y/3)+(4/3))
Y= 1.5y/((2y/3)+(4/3))
```

I am doing geometric transformation of it using the following code:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
T= [    3 0 0; 
        0 4.5 2;
        0 0 4 ];
    t_proj = projective2d(T);
    I_projective = imwarp(I,t_proj,'FillValues',.3);

    figure, subplot(1,2,1); 
    imshow(I); title('Original Image');
    subplot(1,2,2); imshow(I_projective);
    title('Perspective Transform');
```

I am not sure is this output correct. 
[image]

Comment: MATLAB defines the projective matrices as the **transpose** of what is normally accepted in computer graphics.  When you define your matrix using the normal convention, make sure you take the transpose, then find your transformation object (`projective2d`).  I don't believe your geometric transformation is suitable for creating this object.  The matrix is used in order to create output co-ordinates in the output image, which is a linear weighted sum of matrix coefficients.  That division with the variable thus makes the transformation non-linear.  Can you describe what this is supposed to do?

Comment: I don't see the relationship between your X and Y expressions (which are suspect anyway) and your T matrix.  Also, a projective matrix is usually specified with a 1 in the lower right corner.

Comment: Thank you. I have resolved the problem. Actually it was correction in above equations and then it worked like charm :)